# Is there a difference in grades of Dog Residue and Dog Residue byproducts?

Tags: undertale

In the Temmie Shop, different pieces of Dog Residue receive different valuations. Are these pieces of Dog Residue functionally different? Should I save the more expensive ones?

The same applies to Dog Salads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no functional difference between the items. All Dog Residue can only be used to generate even more Dog Residue and the occasional Dog Salad.

Dog Salad is only sold for 8G and has the negotation option when it's the eigth (or a multiple of it) item you sell, at which point it can be sold for either 9G or 13G.